# Observing an event in roboguice application in a custom view

Tags: java, android, roboguice

Basing on the RoboGuice API for firing an event, inside my CustomButtonView implementation I have did like so:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    CommonApplication.getInstance().fireEvent(new InteractionButtonClicked());
    // setSelected();

}

public class InteractionButtonClicked
{
    public String getRef()
    {
        return (String)getTag();
    }

}



// handle the click event
protected void handleClick(@Observes InteractionButtonClicked button) {
    if (getTag().equals(button.getRef())) {
        //do A
    } else {
        //do B
    }
}
```

However, handleClick does not get called in this context=> when I set an @Observer in the main activity it's containing method **does** get called.

I'm trying to understand why, and if there is an option to observe the event in the Customview context...

Comment: Have you tried to inject `EventManager`? `@Inject private EventManager eventMgr; /*...*/ eventMgr.fire(new InteractionButtonClicked());` in your `CustomButtonView`.